# Positive definitness of the expectation of a random matrix

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory, expected-value, positive-definite

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable. We know that if $E[X]= 0$ then $X=0$ a.s. A consequence of this is that $P(X\neq 0)=1$ implies $E[X]>0$.

Now, let $A$ be a $n\times n$ symmetric and non-negative definite random matrix, i.e., for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have that $x^TAx\geq 0$ a.s. Analogous to the real case, can we conclude that $P(A\neq 0)=1$ implies $E[A]$ positive definite, i.e., for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $x^TE[A]x>0$?

I think that this is not true, but I can not think of a counter-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0\\
   0 & 0\\
  \end{bmatrix}$ (i.e. the deterministic matrix chosen with probability $1$). Then $A$ is non-negative definite but $E[A] = A$ is not positive definite.

Comment: Thank! One of those questions that are too obvious that you can't see it...

Comment: Sure! I was thinking of weakening the $P(A\neq 0)=1$ condition to see if there was an interesting matrix analogue, but couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: Yeah. The problem here is that the "zero in the reals" is not the same as the "zero in the symmetric matrices". I mean, if $A\succeq 0$, then $A\neq 0$ doesn't imply $A\succ 0$. One interesting thing is that if $X\geq 0$ (real) and $A\succ 0$ (matrix) then $P(X=0)<1$ implies that $E[XA]\succ 0$ even if $XA\succeq 0$. (You can prove it by contradiction.)